# Only 7 bits for Java char?

Tags: java, bit

I'm trying to make a UUencode algorithm and part of my code contains this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < my_chars.length; x++)
{
   if((x+1) % 3 == 0)
   {
   char first = my_chars[x-2];
   char second = my_chars[x-1];
   char third = my_chars[x];
   int first_binary = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(first));
   int second_binary = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(second));
   int third_binary = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(third));
   int n = (((first << 8) | second) << 8) | third;
   System.out.print(my_chars[x-2] + "" + my_chars[x-1] + my_chars[x] + Integer.toBinaryString(n));

   }
}

System.out.println();
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString('s'));
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to combine those 8 bits from the chars that I get into a big 24 bits int. The problem I'm facing is that the result is a 23 bit int. Say my first 3 chars were:

- 'T' with a binary representation of `01010100`
- 'u' with a binary representation of `01110101`
- 'r' with a binary representation of `01110010`

The result that I get from my program is a int formed from these bits:
`10101000111010101110010`
Which is missing the 0 at the beginning from the representation of 'T'.

Also I have included the last 2 lines of code because the binary string that I get from 's' is: `1110011` which is missing the 0 at the beginning.

I have checked if I scrolled by mistake to the right but it does not seem that I have done so.

Comment: ASCII letters are 7 bit. Everything makes sense. If you're one bit short, you can just think of a leading zero, `n` has 32 bits anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`Integer.toBinaryString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) does not zero-pad the results on the left; you'll have to zero-pad it yourself.

> This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2)
>   with no extra leading 0s.

Comment: So I will have to add an extra 0 at the end? Thanks !

Comment: @Bula the easiest way I could imagine doing this is: `(c < 0 ? "" : "0") + binaryString`. That way if `c`, the character, is negative it will have a 1 in the leading bit slot and require no padding. This is assuming you are only using alphabetic characters like the ones provided in the example.

Comment: So a check weather my string is 23 or 24 bits will tell me weather to add a 0 as my leftmost character? That's great thanks!